# CentOS 7 SSSD LDAP against Windows Server DC fails to authenticate

Tags: active-directory, ldap, centos7, sssd

I'm having an issue for authenticating via LDAP from a CentOS 7 machine to a Windows Server 2012 R2 DC via SSSD.

```
Linux WS100 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 18 15:06:45 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ldapsearch can successfully query the directory, via plain LDAP, with no problems

```
ldapsearch -x -h dc.company.local -D "cn=some user,cn=users,dc=company,dc=local" -w thePassword -b "cn=users,dc=company,dc=local" -s sub "(cn=*)" cn mail sn
```

And these are the steps done to configure SSSD to this purpose

```
yum install sssd sssd-client
authconfig --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --ldapserver=dc.company.local --ldapbasedn="cn=users,dc=company,dc=local" --update
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains the entries for sss

```
passwd: files sss
shadow: files sss
group: files sss
```

And `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` is configured this way:

```
[sssd]
domains = company.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/company.local]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = ad
ldap_uri = ldap://dc.company.local
ldap_search_base = cn=users,dc=company,dc=local
ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=some user,cn=users,dc=company,dc=local
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = thePassword
override_homedir = /home/%u
```

But `su - username` nor su - `username@company.local` does not work. There are network transactions to the domain controller as inspected by tcpdump, but I suppose the credentials are not correctly formatted for the schema I use (ad).

I tried emptying SSSD cache and restarting the daemon, with no difference. I find no related messages in `/var/log/secure`, and `/var/log/sssd/` logs do not point to a misconfiguration.

Can anybody give me a hand? Have you faced a similar issue or may propose another solution doable in a similar setup?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using `id_provider = ad` rather than `ldap` which is what I use in my SSSD configuration against AD. `auth_provider` defaults to the same value as `id_provider` so you can omit that and using the `ad` backend implies `ldap_schema = ad` too.

Comment: I tried, leaving only id_provider = ad, and then the service cannot be started (Failed to read keytab [default]: No such file or directory). I'd like to clarify that I do not want to bind the machine to AD, only enable LDAP-based logins.

Comment: Yes, `sssd-ad(5)` mentions that the machine is required to be joined to AD, (it would then have a keytab file). I would update your question to clarify the situation.

Comment: Many thanks bodgit, just comment that I'd like not to bind the machine to AD...